# Java " " [space] character in CSV dataset

Tags: java, csv, web, char

I have a dataset that calls values and displays them in a .jsp driven graph on a website.

It can also be used to download the .csv data of the graph.

```
private static Dataset initDatasetElec() {
    Dataset datasetElec = new Dataset();
    datasetElec.setSeriesName("Elective Data");
    datasetElec.setAnchorBgColor("0099FF");
    datasetElec.setAnchorBorderThickness("1");
    return datasetElec;
}
```

The problem with this is

```
datasetElec.setSeriesName("Elective Data");
```

The space between the two words is necessary for appearance sake in the graph, and if I leave the space there, the CSV data puts the word `"Data"` onto the next line.

I've tried to use `&nbsp;`, which works in the graph, but breaks the link, and using an underscore looks pretty terrible.

Can you think of any space separator that would work here?

Comment: Where is that `DataSet` class coming from?

Comment: Try `"Elective\U+00A0\Data"`. (See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space).)

Comment: What does the javadoc to `Dataset.setSeriesName()` say? Which `Dataset` is it, from what package? Where's the documentation?